# create a custom resource in kubernetes using generateName field

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-custom-resources

I have a sample crd defined as

crd.yaml

```
kind: CustomResourceDefinition
metadata:
  name: testconfig.demo.k8s.com
  namespace: testns
spec:
  group: demo.k8s.com
  versions:
    - name: v1
      served: true
      storage: true
  scope: Namespaced
  names:
    plural: testconfigs
    singular: testconfig
    kind: TestConfig
```

I want to create a custom resource based on above crd but i dont want to assign a fixed name to the resource rather use the generateName field. So i generated the below cr.yaml. But when i apply it gives error that name field is mandatory

```
kind: TestConfig
metadata:
  generateName: test-name-
  namespace: testns
spec:
  image: testimage
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should use `kubectl create` to create your CR with `generateName`.

"`kubectl apply` will verify the existence of the resources before take action. If the resources do not exist, it will firstly create them. If use `generateName`, the resource name is not yet generated when verify the existence of the resource." [source](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/44501#issuecomment-294255660)